# Grav CMS possibilities

Tags: performance, twig, templating, grav

I just started fiddling with grav and reading their documentation, but I have some questions about what it allows you to do.

In each post, in my markdown file, can I set some yaml or twig variables that link e.g. folder with images, and in template I check if this variable was set and output the Images, and if not I do nothing?

In Wordpress it's quite easy, but I wanted to experiment with something a bit smaller, faster and nicer to write in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, after some time reading [grav documentation](https://learn.getgrav.org/), I found the answer to my question about creating custom fields, and default variables. It's all described in [forms section](https://learn.getgrav.org/forms/) of grav documentation. (The naming is a bit misleading)

And you can read about twig variables and twig in general, in sections [twig filters & functions](https://learn.getgrav.org/themes/twig-filters-functions), and [theme variables](https://learn.getgrav.org/themes/theme-vars).

[Twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation) is really useful as well.

Comment: You should accept your own answer so this doesn't show up as unresolved. :)